# Javascript XMLHttpRequest with formdata sending empty body

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest, multipartform-data, form-data

I tried sending files like this

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("avatar", document.getElementById('imageFile').files[0]);

var request = new XMLHttpRequest;
request.open("PATCH", "http://localhost:9090/users/me/avatar");
request.send(formData);
```

However, no matter what i try the actual content of the selected file that should be sent remains blank. Here's a screenshot of Chrome's network tab

[image: Avatar field is empty]

I tried with different files and different request methods and it's always the same.

I also tried `formData.append("testfield", "some string");` and that is sent correctly, i can see the "some string" in request body, the issue appears to be with files.

Am i doing something wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PATCH` is a method intended for API changes, not sending files.
You should use POST or PUT to upload a file

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("avatar", document.getElementById('imageFile').files[0]);

var request = new XMLHttpRequest;
request.open("POST", "http://localhost:9090/users/me/avatar");
request.send(formData);
```

Also, you won't be able to see the data when logging a `formData` object to the console.

Comment: Thanks, but it's the same, i tried with POST and PUT already and it was the same. Tried it again just now, no difference. This is driving me crazy, seems really weird.

Comment: And if you log `document.getElementById('imageFile').files[0]` what do you get? How are you catching the files on the serverside?

Comment: I'm getting the file i selected logged in console so that's working. Server side at this point doesn't matter because the field "avatar" is sent with no contents, see image above :(

Comment: That's what the request should look like, you won't see the binary data in a POST or PUT request in the console, you still have to catch that file on the server.

Comment: Oh my god i'm stupid. I expected to see something there in the network tab. Turned out that it was an error with my server code, but a really weird one, so i suspected that something was wrong with my client code.

Comment: PS thanks for the help and if you want - write another answer saying that you can't see the actual request data in Chrome network tab for this case (basically what you said in the comment above) and i'll select it as a correct answer - because it is.

Comment: @IanDess - I'll just edit the above answer a little bit